# Exclude headings from CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I added some sub headings to a HTML page but the sub heading causes the columns to display incorrectly as shown in this image.

[image]

I have already tried display block on the sub heading but i assume there's a different method when using display: grid;

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
.grid-item {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
 <div class="grid-container">
  
  <a href="#"><div class="archive-title">Sub Header</div></a>

  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  
  <a href="#"><div class="archive-title">Sub Header</div></a>
  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div> 
  
  <a href="#"><div class="archive-title">Sub Header</div></a>
  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

The sub headings should be 100% width for each row not column.

Comment: Try this in CSS `.archive-title { display: block}`

Comment: Thanks but i added that and it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Use the `grid-column` property for the `.archive-title` divs:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

.archive-title{
  background: lightgray;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  
  <div class="archive-title">Sub Header</div>
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  
  
    <div class="archive-title">Sub Header</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div> 
  
  
    <div class="archive-title">Sub Header</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: The heading should be 100% width.

Comment: I mean only 1 sub header per row

Comment: Works, but doesn't work for me with my code. Not sure why but i'll mark it as the accepted answer. What about if the sub heading is a link?

Comment: @Michelle That's weird. If it helps, in the example code you provide, it works if you add this one line to the CSS: `.archive-title{grid-column: 1/4;}`

Comment: Works when i change the HTML output so the archive-title class is applied to the a tag. Thanks.

Comment: ```.grid-container>a { grid-column: 1/4; }``` if don't want to add that class ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="http://local.local/status/for-sale/"><h1 class="ap-template-sub-heading archive-title">Selling</h1></a>
    <div class="post-500 listing type-listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail types-single-family-home bedrooms-2-bedrooms price-500k-750k state-california city-encino status-for-sale entry">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="listing-wrap">
                <a href="http://local.local/listings/16480-oldham-street/"><img width="500" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=Placeholder" class="attachment-properties size-properties" alt=""></a><span class="listing-price">$100,000</span><span class="listing-text">For Sale</span><span class="listing-address">Address</span><span class="listing-city-state-zip">State</span><a href="http://local.local/listings/16480-oldham-street/" class="more-link">Listing</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-498 listing type-listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail features-basement types-single-family-home bedrooms-3-bedrooms price-200k-500k state-california city-encino status-for-sale entry">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="listing-wrap">
                <a href="http://local.local/listings/16520-adlon-road/"><img width="500" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=Placeholder" class="attachment-properties size-properties" alt=""></a><span class="listing-price">$100,000</span><span class="listing-text">Sold</span><span class="listing-address">Address</span><span class="listing-city-state-zip">State</span><a href="http://local.local/listings/16520-adlon-road/" class="more-link">Listing</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-489 listing type-listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail types-single-family-home bedrooms-3-bedrooms price-200k-500k state-california city-encino status-for-sale entry">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="listing-wrap">
                <a href="http://local.local/listings/4010-rogen-drive/"><img width="500" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=Placeholder" class="attachment-properties size-properties" alt=""></a><span class="listing-price">$100,000</span><span class="listing-text">For Sale</span><span class="listing-address">Address</span><span class="listing-city-state-zip">State</span><a href="http://local.local/listings/4010-rogen-drive/" class="more-link">Listing</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div><a href="http://local.local/status/sold/"><h1 class="ap-template-sub-heading archive-title">Sold</h1></a>

    <div class="post-488 listing type-listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail types-single-family-home bedrooms-4-bedrooms price-500k-750k state-california city-encino status-for-sale entry">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="listing-wrap">
                <a href="http://local.local/listings/17055-mooncrest-drive/"><img width="500" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=Placeholder" class="attachment-properties size-properties" alt=""></a><span class="listing-price">$100,000</span><span class="listing-text">For Sale</span><span class="listing-address">Address</span><span class="listing-city-state-zip">State</span><a href="http://local.local/listings/17055-mooncrest-drive/" class="more-link">Listing</a></div>
        </div>
    <div class="post-504 listing type-listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail types-single-family-home bedrooms-4-bedrooms price-500k-750k state-california city-encino status-sold entry">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="listing-wrap">
                <a href="http://local.local/listings/17038-cotter-place/"><img width="500" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=Placeholder" class="attachment-properties size-properties" alt=""></a><span class="listing-price">$100,000</span><span class="listing-text">Sold</span><span class="listing-address">Address</span><span class="listing-city-state-zip">State</span><a href="http://local.local/listings/17038-cotter-place/" class="more-link">Listing</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-496 listing type-listing status-publish has-post-thumbnail types-single-family-home bedrooms-4-bedrooms price-500k-750k state-california city-encino status-sold entry">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="listing-wrap">
                <a href="http://local.local/listings/16760-octavia-place/"><img width="500" height="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300&text=Placeholder" class="attachment-properties size-properties" alt=""></a><span class="listing-price">$100,000</span><span class="listing-text">For Sale</span><span class="listing-address">Address</span><span class="listing-city-state-zip">State</span><a href="http://local.local/listings/16760-octavia-place/" class="more-link">Listing</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Issue was that the **Sold** link was appearing after the fourth card. Now the link is added after the third card.

Comment: No, the sub heading should be added after the 4th entry however the Sold listings should display inline. Clearly, the Sold listings and Sold sub heading are not cleared properly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

First you can add the "Sold" hyperlink after thrid element listing..it'll be great.
 If you are not able to do that so you have to use **DISPLAY : FLEX** property..In display flex property you can easily change the order of the element...so can try the display flex...

Comment: You can also check the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mayank0619/h0rb4p3y/6/

Comment: Thanks for your help however, my problem is caused by adding the sub headings, not the columns alone. It has something to do with float clearing.